# Automate Java Class using TimerTask

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, data-structures, medical

I have a small problem with a Java project that I've been working on for a University class (Data Structures). The assignment is to build a small and basic Java Application for a Clinic/Hospital which allows patients to be added to a queue (Using Queues or Stacks) according to the emergency they have (Emergency, Urgency, Medical Appointment or just a Medical Visit).

The app is built using Swing. There are three jTextArea, which are filled in order using the queue system after clicking one of the 4 buttons for the reason they are visiting the Clinic/Hospital that day(mentioned above).

There's another button to get the patient out of the every queue (jTextArea) after the has been treated. The problem I have is that I want to automate this process. Basically, I want every patient to leave the queue after a certain time without clicking the "patient treated" which btw gets activated only when there's data inside the jTextArea. I tried using the TimerTask, but failed. Is there another option for doing this?

This is how I add/remove data into the jTextArea. Pointing to a node or removing the pointing of a node.

```
public String DatosATextArea1() {
    String valor = "";

    if (primero_1.getSigPaciente() != null) {
        Paciente data = primero_1.getSigPaciente();
        //Appends information of all the nodes to the string to be returned.
        while (data != null) {
            valor += data.getNombre() + "\t" + data.getIdentidad() + "\t" + data.getPrioridad() + "\n";
            data = data.getSigPaciente();
        }
    } else {
        valor = "La Clinica esta Vacia!";
    }
    return valor;
}
```

Here is how the program looks:
[Main screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hZAL.png)

After clicking the "Atentido" button, this code is executed:

```
public void atenderClinica1() {
    String valor = pQ.getPrimero1();
    if (valor != null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Salio el Paciente: " + valor);
    } else {
        callButton1.setEnabled(false);
    }
    clinica1.setText(pQ.DatosATextArea1());
}
```

This is the timer I have:

```
public SalaEmergencia(int seconds) {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new ReminderTask(), seconds * 1000);
}

class ReminderTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Salio un paciente.");
        timer.cancel();
    }
}
```

Using that Timer, I tried to create a class that determined the type of emergency of the first person in Queue and according to that, assign a certain amount of seconds before it automatically triggers the "patient treated" option.

```
public final void timerClinica1() {
    String valor = pQ.getPrimero1();
    int priority = p.getPrioridad();
    String prio = Integer.toString(priority);

    if (valor != null) {
        if ("1".equals(prio)) {
            SalaEmergencia sE = new SalaEmergencia(5);
        }
        if ("2".equals(prio)) {
            SalaEmergencia sE = new SalaEmergencia(7);
        }
        if ("3".equals(prio)) {
            SalaEmergencia sE = new SalaEmergencia(15);
        }
        if ("4".equals(prio)) {
            SalaEmergencia sE = new SalaEmergencia(20);
        }
    } else {
        callButton1.setEnabled(false);
    }
    clinica1.setText(pQ.DatosATextArea1());
}
```

After adding this function and calling in when clicking the add patients buttons, nothing gets added to the jTextArea. I use SysOut to print what the program is doing in console and I got that the timer gets activated correctly and that it prints that the patient was treated, yet no data is added to the jTextArea. Maybe I'm adding the timerClinica1() wrong?